# Lists web service globalization

Tags: web-services

How are the globalization settings for the Lists web service defined?

I have a web with locale set to Finnish.

When I insert list items to a list, I am unable to enter them in the Finnish format, using commas as decimal separators. The web services are always using (I'm assuming) en-US locale.

E.g.:

- `<Field Name='number1'>2,5</Field>` becomes `25`
- `<Field Name='number2'>2500,50</Field>` becomes `250050`

Comment: Have you found solution for your issue? I have similar problem: when I fetch Fields with Lists.asmx#GetList all DisplayNames are in en-US locale. How can I switch to other one?

Comment: I have not found a solution to this. I was able to work around the number formatting issue. I would be interested to find a solution though.

Comment: Maybe it's better to fetch server locale first, and act according to it (e.g., server returns en-US but your app in the Finnish - you just format it back and forth on a client side)?